# Script error in review page

Tags: bug, status-completed, javascript, review

Getting script error in review page, due to this, when clicking on "show full answer" link or any other link in that page. That particualr functionality is not working.
Please find screenshot below.

Error information:

> Expected identifier, string or number
>   Line: 72
>   Char: 9
>   URL: https://stackoverflow.com/review/

[image: review page error]

[image: script error]

Comment: IE 7, 8 or 9?..

Comment: IE7, i tested in mozilla, there its works fine

Comment: @Damodar I fear that IE7 is [minimally supported](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/56161/which-browsers-are-officially-supported-and-what-else-do-i-need/71208#71208) - try upgrading to IE8 and see if this still persist.

Comment: will let u know , iam at office, i cannot upgrade it here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Trailing-comma issue, as usual when it's IE7-only. Fix is simple enough, so it should work after the next build.

You might still want to think about upgrading; IE7 is the new IE6. Unless it's trivial fixes like this, we more and more err on the side of "if it kinda works in IE7, that's more than good enough."

Comment: +1 for being brave enough to override Jeff himself! ;)